# Floating point to 8-bit unsigned raster conversion using ArcGIS for Desktop or ERDAS IMAGINE?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, erdas-imagine

I have an image with value ranging from -1 to +1.

I want to convert this into 0-255 (8bit).

How can this be done using ArcGIS for Desktop or ERDAS IMAGINE?

Comment: is it floating point? i.e. are values -1, 0 or 1 or decimal values between -1 and 1? Note 8 bit can also be signed 8 bit, just not seen very often (-127 to 128)

Comment: yes I have decimal values also.

Answer (score 3):

You will want to stretch your floating point data from (-1 to 1) to (0 - 255).  You can accomplish this very easily in Erdas Imagine:

Raster tab > Resolution Group > Radiometric > Rescale

---

[image]

Comment: That does sound easier Aaron. I reckon that would be the way to do it... almost makes me wish I got around to learning how to use ERDAS.

Comment: In this case, rescaling data is very easy in Erdas--it eliminates a few steps that you describe using ArcGIS.  Any type of bulk image processing is almost always more efficient and easier in Erdas.  It is definitely worth a look.

Answer (score 2):

Using [ArcGis Raster Calculator](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000z7000000) multiply by 127 and then add 128. This will give you a value between 0 and 255 which will be floating point then use [Int](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Int/009z0000008z000000/) to convert to an integer and [Copy Raster](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000094000000) specifying 8 bit unsigned as the output pixel_type.

Another way to do this is to do a nice stretch in ArcMap and then right click on the layer, select data::export data then check the box *Use Renderer* which will force the data into 8 bit using the colour scheme you have applied (and even optionally RGB).

Comment: It is @Aaron, but it only works for 8 bit. If you use a colour ramp with *real* colours then that what you get - a pseudocolour 8 bit image not monochrome. It can be handy to 'freeze' your elevation etc. data into a specific colouration rather than trying to apply the same ramp and stretch on multiple workstations/occasions so it's a good-to-know technique. You just have to remember when you're using the rendered output you can't use hover/identify to get values because now it's RGB or pseudocolour.