# Calculating average NDVI

Tags: spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, statistics, ndvi

I would like to calculate average NDVI values. I have 3 values of NDVI:

1. high:243 low:0
2. high:243 low:0
3. high:238 low:0

How can I use a a raster calculator to calculate the average valvue

Comment: Which software do you use? Have you tried to google solution for your issue?

Comment: Please make a minimal attempt to research your question and provide detail on what you have tried and your preferred software. A GUI software solution will vary considerably from a programming one. I performed search for "NDVI time" (http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=NDVI+time), on this site, and immediately found several threads that answer your question using various solutions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I average a set of rasters?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44793/how-do-i-average-a-set-of-rasters)

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to approach this.  One option is to use the [Raster Calculator](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000z7000000), as you indicated.  I see that your NDVI values have been rescaled from floating point (-1 to 1) to unsigned 8-bit integer (0 - 255).  This is the syntax you would use in the raster calculator:

```
("ndvi_1" + "ndvi_2" + "ndvi_3") / 3
```

You can also use [Cell Statistics (Spatial Analyst)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z0000007q000000) with the "MEAN" statistic to perform the same calculation.

Comment: thanks so much for the answers however I would like the NDVI values to be ranged from (-1 to 1) not (0-255) as it is being shown now so that I may come up with a graph showing variations of NDVI in a year. how should I go about it

Comment: You should consider updating your question to reflect that you need to rescale 8-bit unsigned integer to float.  If you have access to Erdas, this is easily accomplished with the rescale tool: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/114262/8104.  However, you would want to set the min max range different than the example.

Comment: Yes Aaron, I need to rescale the bit-integer to float. how can I do it in ArcGIS 9.3, I don't have Erdas at the moment